# Export ntopng log to logstash

Tags: logstash

I know ntopng can put direct to elasticsearch but my boss want use logtash as layer to transfer log to elasticsearch.

I'm try many time but failed.

ntopng log like:

```
{"index": {"_type": "ntopng", "_index": "ntopng-2016.08.23"}}
{ "@timestamp": "2016-08-23T01:49:41.0Z", "type": "ntopng", "IN_SRC_MAC": "04:2A:E2:0D:62:FB", "OUT_DST_MAC": "00:16:3E:8D:B7:E4", "IPV4_SRC_ADDR": "14.152.84.14", "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "xxx.xxx.xxx", "L4_SRC_PORT": 34599, "L4_DST_PORT": 53, "PROTOCOL": 17, "L7_PROTO": 5, "L7_PROTO_NAME": "DNS", "IN_PKTS": 15, "IN_BYTES": 1185, "OUT_PKTS": 15, "OUT_BYTES": 22710, "FIRST_SWITCHED": 1471916981, "LAST_SWITCHED": 1471916981, "SRC_IP_COUNTRY": "CN", "SRC_IP_LOCATION": [ 113.250000, 23.116699 ], "DST_IP_COUNTRY": "VN", "DST_IP_LOCATION": [ 105.849998, 21.033300 ], "NTOPNG_INSTANCE_NAME": "ubuntu", "INTERFACE": "ens192", "DNS_QUERY": "cpsc.gov", "PASS_VERDICT": true }
```

Logstash config:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json
  }
}
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 }
 stdout{ codec => rubydebug  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ntopng logs are already in the bulk format expected by Elasticsearch you don't need to use the `elasticsearch` output but you can use the `http` output directly like this. No need to have Logstash parse JSON, simply forward the raw bulk commands to ES.

There's one catch, though: we need to add a newline character after the second line otherwise ES will reject the bulk call. We can achieve this with a `mutate/update` filter that adds a verbatim newline character after the `message`. Try it out, this will work.

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => multiline {
       pattern => "_index"
       what => "next"
    }
  }
}
filter{
  mutate {
    update => {"message" => "%{message}
"}
  }
}
output {
    http {
        http_method => "post"
        url => "http://localhost:9200/_bulk"
        format => "message"
        message => "%{message}"
    }
}
```

Comment: The new edit still not working, thanks for your help